# Deferred loading of RadGrid and strange error in firefox

Tags: jquery, telerik, radgrid, deferred-loading

I have some strange issues with loading of RadGrid.
What I'm trying to accomplish is deferred loading user control from web service.
This technique is explained on this link:

http://encosia.com/2008/02/05/boost-aspnet-performance-with-deferred-content-loading

In explorer and chrome works fine except, styling of a grid is not applied.
In firefox, when I call web service from client side, I get blank screen and firebug shows error:

RadGridNamespace is not defined

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably indicates RadGrid's scripts are not loaded on page by the time the grid object is initialized.

Comment: yes, I think that is too..do you know how to init rad grid to initialize without those scripts or at least to loads them in the end?

Comment: The classic RadGrid for ASP.NET (using the **RadGridNamespace**) cannot function without its client scripts. What exactly are you trying to implement?

Comment: nothing special..I am just loading serialized radgrid by calling web service witch prepare control, bind it, and then serialize it and returns to jquery...on return I put recieved control in div on page...but, page throws js error, as I explained above, and it is obviosly because of radgrid client side initialization took place after my scripts and not before as it should be...so, I need to somehow tell grid when to loads scripts or to turn them off..

Comment: All right. Can you modify the RadGrid markup after it's been rendered? If you can, search for any <script> tags inside and remove them from the markup. This way, you will not render any scripts that try to initialize the RadGrid client object.

Comment: yes, that is the solution, dirty one, but the solution...I rather like to just turn it off or somehow control it's loading if I can...

Answer (score 0):

Another thing is to get rid of the old Telerik ASP.NET grid and use its ASP.NET AJAX replacement. It is true ASP.NET AJAX control and supports declarative/programmatic client binding to web services as well as other cool client features.

Comment: Yes, especially for the scenario discussed in this topic, the RadGrid for ASP.NET AJAX (as well as all the other AJAX controls) provide the **RegisterWithScriptManager** property, which, when set to **false**, allows the control to be renderable outside the regular AJAX page lifecycle. Thus, you can easily render the control and send its HTML back from the AJAX request. Upgrading to [RadControls for ASP.NET AJAX][http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-ajax.aspx] is recommended for richer client and server capabilities.Plus, they see active improvement and support.